# Make sure all members of an object implement some version of a generic interface

Tags: typescript

Is it possible for a TypeScript index signature type to declare that every index implements some version of a generic interface? I'd like to write code like this:

```
interface HasState<T> {
  state : T;
}

interface ModuleDefinition {
  [moduleName : string] : <T>HasState<T>;
}
```

Here's my use-case:

I have a TypeScript mapped type for an object:

```
interface ModuleDefinition {
  [moduleName : string] : HasState;
}

interface HasState {
  state : any;
}
```

This code ensures that every value in a ModuleDefinition object has a parameter named state.

However, if I use this mapped type to try to unwrap the state objects:

```
type UnwrappedModules<Mod extends ModuleDefinition> = {
  [K in keyof Mod] : Mod[K]["state"];
}
```

and declare and use a function

```
function unwrap<Mod extends ModuleDefinition>(mod: Mod) : UnwrappedModules<Mod> {
  // ...
}

const result = unwrap({
  apple: {
    state: {
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
}).apple
```

`result` has type any, instead of `{ color : string }`, like I would expect. Is there a way to make TypeScript infer the correct type here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this!  The solution is to look at the problem backwards: you can use mapped types to *wrap* even if you can't use them to *unwrap*:

```
type StateWrapped<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: HasState<T[K]>;
}
```

Instead of your `unwrap()` function accepting an input of the plain type `T` and returning an unwrapped `T`, it can take an input of the *wrapped* `T` and return the plain `T`:

```
function unwrap<T>(mod: StateWrapped<T>): T {
  var ret = {} as T;
  for (var k in mod) {
    ret[k] = mod[k].state;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

This all type-checks, and has the result you were looking for:

```
const result = unwrap({
  apple: {
    state: {
      color: 'red'
    }
  },
  banana: {
    state: {
      ripe: false
    }
  }
});
console.log(result.apple.color.charAt(0));
console.log(result.banana.ripe);
```

Hope that helps!